# connect two routers using fiber optic

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i moved to a village in turkey from uk. the house i am renting is on the edge of a forest, with no phone line. phone companies wont supply a line here.i suppose the house is illegally built. nearest house is about 250 meters away. can i connect with their wifi router via a fiber optic cable? cat7-8 ethernet cables have a maximum range of 100 meters. i am about 250 meters away. even the wifi range extenders wont work due to the distance. though i have a straight line of sight with the other house.
any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Comment: @davidgo Why was it downvoted, I don't see any downvotes?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - not your or my comment - the original post was downvoted - I upvoted it so its now at 0 rather then -1.  (I am sure it wasn't you, but I hate it when people silently downvote)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use fiber optic cable to connect to their router (but you would want to connect to in on an ethernet port, rather then to the WIFI.

If you can see there house from your roof, it is also entirely practical to set up a point-to-point WIFI connection to it - and, I expect, will be cheaper then laying a fiber optic cable.  To be clear, you would not use a WIFI extender, you would need a dedicated AP client on 1 end, and probably would want a dedicated Access point on the other.   (With the correct aerials, you can go over 10kms, so 250 meters is not hard).  There are no doubt many other manufacturers who can help you, but [Ubiquity](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#default) make very affordable, reliable solutions for long distance links.    You should get lots of change from US$1000 if you can install it yourself.

I also point out there are other options - although probably not as good as fibre - You could lay copper cables and run your own DSL system (you would use a DSL modem on 1 end, but would need special equipment on the other) - possibly something like [this](http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product.php?id=49031#spec).

Comment: nice answer David. i just purchased two Engenius EOC5610's on ebay for about $20u.s each to do something very similar to this.